# homeomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $D_2:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\leq 2\}$ , $D_1:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2< 1\}$ , $K_1:=(-1,1)\times (-1,1)$ and $K_2:=[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$, $A:=D_2-K_1$ and $B:=K_2-D_1$. Show that $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic.

---

Is the proof very easy? I know that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the closed square and the closed disk are homeomorphic. But I don't know whether it is useful. Any hint will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Have you drawn pictures of this yet?

Comment: First I had just the pictures. Then I tried to write the question formally.

Answer (score 0):

[![Describing A and B 
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDlkT.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDlkT.jpg)

For A lets draw a circle containing the square $K_1$ that is the circumcirlce of $K_1$. Now A=$S^1\times S^1 \cup \ ( sectors)$ as in the picture.

For B you can do the same thing drawing a incirlce of $K_2$. So now we just have to show that 4 sectors arising in the pictures of A and B are homoemorphic. But each of this is homeomorphic to a disc hence they are homeomorphic.

Comment: Could you give more detail please? For example how can we show that A and $S^1 \times [0,1]$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: I make an edit to my answer